# How to keep logged instance (httpwebrequest) alive and query another page with it?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, connection, keep-alive

After I've succesfully logged into website using POST variables by httpwebrequest and got response by HttpWebResponse ..How do I query other websites with the "current logged in" instance? Do I save it to some variable??

Answer (score 1):

`POST` variables are accessed server side, and user state would typically be stored with a cookie or in a session.

The `HttpWebResponse` class offers a `Cookies` collection that you can use to save the encrypted authentication data or session key for use in future `HttpWebRequest` under `HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer`.

Of course, this is all under the assumption that the initial request stores the user authentication data in one of these forms.